# Permissions for subfolders Owncloud

Tags: linux, file, permissions, file-permissions, owncloud

I want to give permissions for subfolders in Owncloud.
Example:
a user can edit and read all the files in a synchronized folder except some specific subfolders.

Im working with desktop client and web interface. Version: OwnCloud 8.0.3 (stable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know a user has access to all his/her folders and files, plus any files that are shared with him/her by other users. You cannot restrict access to user's files  if they are in that user's account.

My assumption is that you are an administrator and can create accounts, etc. A workaround might be the following, but it is a workaround and not the solution you've asked for:

If there are some files that you'd like more than one user, or only specific users to be able to view; you can share them using the web interface.

You could create a master user who has access to all files and then share with the other users from the master account.

If anyone knows any different to this please suggest an edit to my answer and I'll put it in.

Comment: Thank you for answer =D. But i need some alternative

Comment: Ok no problem. In order for others to help I think you may need to give more detail of your requirements. With owncloud, the file permissions in the "data" folder are the same for all files, it is read, write, execute for the user running the apache server (assuming you're using aache), usually www-data. The file sharing and viewing permissions between users are controlled using the sharing facilities within the owncloud web application. This is why I suggested setting up a master user. They can then grant access to specific users in the web app, and can choose read or write permissions.

Comment: The shared files will then be downloaded and synced by the individual user's desktop clients.

Comment: I think what I say at first might not can be done, but thank you for all!!